Firebase: Sending messages to selected user (device token)
There is a task to send messages to about 4000 subscribers that the money on the balance has run out. This happens once a month at the same time. I see that you can only send to the topic. Do I understand correctly that I add the right customers to the "top up the balance" topic and then send a message to the group? Are there any restrictions on adding a client to a group if I do it through the API in one fell swoop? _)

This does not sounds like the right use-case for sending to a topic. Keep in mind that any user can subscribe their own token to any topic, which seems against what you need.
For this use-case, you'll want to send an individual message to each user. Keep in mind that FCM sends tens-of-millions of messages per second, so your 4,000 messages are just a blip for it. You won't even be close to the default quota yet, which (currently) allows for 600K send calls per minute. And even on your own server, making 4,000 calls to the FCM send API should not use a lot resources for very long.
I recommend also studying the documented best practices when sending FCM messages at scale, which explains how to spread out traffic spikes and make the most out of your quota.
